# Python dictionary runs out of memory

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to code this problem on hackerrank.com:

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/find-strings

My code runs nicely for the small cases, but my dictionary quickly runs out of memory in the big cases. What can I do to solve this? I don't want to use a list because then it will take too long to check if an entry is already there... Here is my code:

```
n = int(raw_input())
words = []
for x in range(n):
    words.append(raw_input())
test = int(raw_input())
queries = []
for x in range(test):
    queries.append(raw_input())

dict_of_subwords = {}
for x in words:
    len_of_x = len(x)
    for i in range(len_of_x):
        for j in range(i, len_of_x):
            dict_of_subwords[x[i:j+1]] = 1

list_of_subwords = dict_of_subwords.keys()
list_of_subwords.sort()
for x in queries:
    try:
        print list_of_subwords[int(x)-1]
    except:
        print "INVALID"
```

Comment: btw try using `set_of_subwords = set()` instead of `dict_of_subwords = {}`.

Comment: I should have said, I've tried sets as well and am getting the same error.

Comment: So far I fail to reproduce it; the biggest `n` in the problem is 50, so I tried to feed the algorithm with 50 random 50-character strings, without any ill effects. Please post the exact error message. Also, try calculating `x[i:j+1]` on a separate line, to make sure it's the `dict_of_subwords` access causing the problem.

Comment: It's not an error on my machine. It's only an error on the website (they restrict the amount of memory you can use). The only error I get from them is: 2.82s : MemoryError thrown on line 15

Comment: My suspicion is that you generate a lot of small objects (substrings) in the innermost loop, and garbage collector fails to react timely. Try to factor out finding the set of unique substrings on one string into a function. Then call this function in a loop and combine the sets.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the many suggestions on making a more memory-efficient version, here's a version that attempts to minimize the amount of storage (while still using the same algorithmic approach):

```
subwords = set()

num_words = int(raw_input())
for i in xrange(num_words):
    word = raw_input()
    for i in xrange(len(word)):
        for j in xrange(i, len(word)):
            subwords.add(word[i:j+1])

subwords = sorted(subwords)

num_queries = int(raw_input())
for x in range(num_queries):
    query = raw_input()
    try:
        print subwords[int(query)-1]
    except:
        print "INVALID"
```

Comment: Same problem. I tried running it, and I get: MemoryError thrown on line 8

Comment: That means that it's the approach that's flawed, not the code. This method builds a large amount of substrings, and stores all of them. You need a more memory-efficent algorithm. Have you looked at suffix arrays? They re-use the same string and simply refer to indexes within the string. So instead of each 'string' requiring a new object, you can store a reference and index within the existing string.

Answer (score 0):

You ve to use suffix array, [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array)

[suffix array implementation in python:](https://code.google.com/p/pysuffix/)

**Suffix arrays are closely related to suffix trees:**

- Suffix arrays can be constructed by performing a depth-first traversal of a suffix tree. The suffix array corresponds to the leaf-labels given in the order in which these are visited during the traversal, if edges are visited in the lexicographical order of their first character.
- A suffix tree can be constructed in linear time by using a combination of suffix and LCP array. For a description of the algorithm, see the corresponding section in the LCP array article.